# How to use the inv-laplace transform to find solution to an inv-z-transform problem

Tags: laplace-transform

(This relates to the study of signals and systems)

You know: $H(z) = \frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}z^{-1}+z^{-2}}$

Say for some reason you wanted to be able to use the inverse Laplace transform to solve inverse z-transform problems. What is H(s)? Do you simply replace z with s?

Assuming you can get the inverse Laplace transform of H(s), what needs to be done to the result of inv_laplace(H(s)), if anything, so that the answer matches the inverse z-transform of H(z)?

Comment: No. Why would you want to go to the Laplace transform domain ? And for going from $s$ to $z$ you need the Shannon [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem)

Comment: Of course the simplest case is $h(t) = e^{at} 1_{t > 0} \implies H(s)= \frac{1}{s+a}$ which becomes after sampling $x(n) = h(n/T) = e^{an/T}1_{n \ge 0} \implies X(z) = \frac{1}{1-e^{a/T} z^{-1}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{{1 \over 1 - \root{2}z^{-1} +z^{-2}} =
> {z^{2} \over z^{2} - \root{2}z + 1}.\quad
> r = {\root{2} \over 2} + {\root{2} \over 2}\,\ic = \expo{\pi\ic/4}\quad \mbox{and}\quad \bar{r}\quad}$ are the
>   
>   roots of
>   $\ds{z^{2} - \root{2}z + 1 = 0}$.

---

With $\ds{\quad c > \root{2}/2\quad\mbox{and}\quad t > 0}$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{c - \infty\ic}^{c + \infty\ic}{z^{2} \over z^{2} - \root{2}z + 1}\,
\expo{tz}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\int_{c - \infty\ic}^{c + \infty\ic}{z^{2} \over
\pars{z - \bar{r}}\pars{z - r}}\,\expo{tz}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\bar{r}^{2} \over \bar{r} - r}\,\exp\pars{\bar{r}t} +
{r^{2} \over r - \bar{r}}\,\exp\pars{rt} =
{-\ic \over -\root{2}\ic}\,\exp\pars{\bar{r}t} +
{\ic \over \root{2}\ic}\,\exp\pars{rt}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{2}\,\Re\bracks{\exp\pars{tr}} =
\bbx{\ds{%
\root{2}\exp\pars{{\root{2} \over 2}\,t}\cos\pars{{\root{2} \over 2}\,t}}}
\end{align}